# Use Embedded Service Pre-Chat values submitted by customer

Tags: pre-chat, einstein-bots, embedded-services

We have a working chatbot that is set to have a pre-chat form gather the customers name and email. This form is configured through the standard pre-chat form option in the Embedded Service Deployment.

When starting a flow within the chatbot, I am unable to retrieve that customer input of the email. The main purpose is we need to use the email to look up and match a contact, and also look up to a custom object containing emails.

Is there a way to store/retrieve that pre-chat email value to be used in a flow?

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the pre chat values in embedded service deployment

Setup -> Embedded Service Deployment Settings -> Pre chat -> add pre chat fields

Setup -> Messaging Settings -> open -> Parameter Mappings -> map the Pre chat parameter with flow variable (you need to create variable in the flow)

Setup -> Embedded Service Deployment Settings -> Publish

When the customer will filling the pre chat data from chat you will getting the parameter in the flow automatically.